# How does R dplyr decide precedence between comparison and "or" operators?

Tags: r, dplyr

The book *R for Data Science* [gives this example](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#logical-operators)

```
library(nycflights13)
library(tidyverse)

filter(flights, month == 11 | 12)
```

The result is that `dplyr` filters for all flights where month == 1, because "it finds all months that equal 11 | 12, an expression that evaluates to TRUE"

Why does it do "11 | 12" first, then do the comparison? Shouldn't it first do "month == 11", then "or" that with 12, return a vector of all TRUE, and therefore return everything?

Below shows R giving precedence to `==` over `|`:

```
> 3 == 5 | 7

[1] TRUE
> 3 == (5 | 7)

[1] FALSE
```

Comment: I read your question incorrectly. You are correct about the error in precedence logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The result is that dplyr filters for all flights where month == 1

That's not true, the filter does nothing and returns the original data frame.

```
filter(flights, month == 11 | 12) %>% dim()
# [1] 336776     19
dim(flights)
# [1] 336776     19
```

> Why does it do "11 | 12" first, then do the comparison?

Not true as well, it compares `month == 11` first which gives a logical vector and turns into all TRUE when `| 12` since `12` evaluates to TRUE.

> R giving precedence to == over |

This is the correct statement.

---

You can refer to operator precedence in R [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), ***from highest to lowest***:

```
:: :::  access variables in a namespace
$ @ component / slot extraction
[ [[    indexing
^   exponentiation (right to left)
- + unary minus and plus
:   sequence operator
%any%   special operators (including %% and %/%)
* / multiply, divide
+ - (binary) add, subtract
< > <= >= == != ordering and comparison
!   negation
& &&    and
| ||    or
~   as in formulae
-> ->>  rightwards assignment
<- <<-  assignment (right to left)
=   assignment (right to left)
?   help (unary and binary)
```

Comment: Could be the book is out of date, I suppose. Or maybe it's just an error/typo in the book.

Comment: I see; it's a mistake in the book. Thank you.

Comment: @joran Yeah. I didn't read the book part first, but I guess it's a bit miss logic there.

Comment: @42 Appreciate the effort for digging through the source, but I guess it does have some logic flaw there. ***You can’t write `filter(flights, month == 11 | 12)`, which you might literally translate into “finds all flights that departed in November or December”. Instead it finds all months that equal `11 | 12`, an expression that evaluates to TRUE. In a numeric context (like here), TRUE becomes one, so this finds all flights in January, not November or December. ***  See the last sentence ***so this finds all flights in January, not November or December***.

Comment: @hadley: At worst that is somewhat unclear as to the reasoning, but it clearly states "you can't do that". It does find all months == 11  and ORs that with the number 12 which results in a logical value of TRUE for all rows. I guess there is an error in concluding that it gets restricted to January, There is no filtering. All months are returned.

Comment: @42- It's possible you've parsed the sentence different than I do. I guess it's fair to say the statement contains some ambiguity here.

Comment: I've come around to your viewpoint... clearly an error in the author's use of precedence rules.